# Update appx without uninstall

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, visual-studio-cordova

I'm developing an HTML app wrapped with cordova, to be deployed via mdm to corporate Windows Phone 8.1 devices, and I'm facing problems updating the app without deleting a previous version.

Every time I regenerate the VS solution with cordova tools, when I try to run the app from VS2013 to my device, I get a message saying app already exists, and it will be deleted and then installed again.

When I create the appx and try to install it using 'Windows Phone Application Deployment 8.1', if the app is not yet installed in the device, it works ok, but if it was previously installed, deployment fails with no error details.

Is there any way to update the app without previously uninstalling it, so I don't loose app data?

Answer (score 0):

Change the app version from the `config.xml` file or change the package name and try again

Comment: Already changed the app version in `config.xml`. I can't change package name. If I do so, the app will be installed as a different one, and what I want to do is to update the existing application with a new version, without loosing the app data.

Comment: Changing the package name would leave the old version on the device and the new version could not access any data of the old version, right?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have entered a world of pain and you have my sympathy.

There are a number of things you must know about what you are trying to do.

1. Cordova by default builds appxbundles, but in order to make an app upgradable through an MDM like Intune, this has to be an appx and not a appxbundle.  Add an AppxBundle property to the CordovaApp.Phone.jsproj with value "Never".
2. The PhoneIdentity PhoneProductID and PhonePublisherId in the AppxManifest must be the same for both the app you have installed and the app you are upgrading.  By default, the PhoneProductID will be randomly generated by cordova each time (I used a before build hook to change this each time - as we use command line drive cordova).
3. Getting an appx to deploy through an MDM requires you to include all dependencies in your code base. Including the WinJS which cordova will use.  Download the code of your dependencies, place into your code and update your references to use it.
4. In order to get an Appx to deploy through an MDM you need to put in a Dll into your code base, so that the signing process will produce a code integrity cat file.  In order to make the app upgradable through the MDM, you will need to alter the DLL every time (both the code - eg. a new method in a class) and increment the version.  There is a cordova plugin for adding the DLL, but it doesn't support the upgrade path, so you are best building a Portable Class Libray DLL yourself.
5. To deploy through the Airwatch MDM, you need to set the TargetFrameworkMoniker to "WindowsPhoneApp,Version=8.1" in the AppxManifest by altering the CordovaApp.Phone.jsproj file by adding TargetFrameworkIdentifier set to WindowsPhoneApp and TargetFrameworkVersion set to 8.1 to the PropertyGroup section.  Otherwise it won't recognise it as a windows phone app.

Here is a presentation I put together a couple of months ago about deploying enterprise cordova apps onto windows devices.  This will address many of the problems you are addressing, will address or given up on.
http://www.slideshare.net/adambirr/enterprisecorodva